# nginx configuration index.html different path

Tags: nginx, nginx-location, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm going crazy with the nginx configuration.

I have this directory tree
site

```
|-- .tmp
|    +-- partials
|    |    |-- partial.js
|    |    |     
|    +-- serve
|         +-- app
|         |    |-- app.css
|         |
|         |-- index.html
|
+-- libs
|    +-- folder_a
|    |        
|    +-- folder_b
|
+-- transpiled
|    +-- app
|    |    |-- app.js
```

Also in my index.html I have the paths like

```
<script src="../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="app/app.js"></script>
```

So, if I'm right, my root should be the transpiled directory.

What is a valid nginx configuration for serving my site ?

#### conf example added

```
 http {
    server {
          
       location / {
           root html/my_site;
           index .tmp/serve/index.html;
           try_files $uri transpiled/$uri;
       }
    }
}
```

I don't know nginx but i have read something about try_files.
try_files directive should search the file $uri into transpiled/$uri.
So if i have *app/app.js* try files should search the file in *transpiled/app/app.js*

This won't work

Comment: You can set any root you want and that root can aliased to `transpiled` directory. You need to post your nginx config and then ask specific issues if you have any

Comment: Do you mean that i have to change the script src to "transpiled/app/app.js" too ?

Comment: No i mean at nginx level you can easily reroute stuff to any directory. So not necessary to have `transpiled` in the url

Comment: I have added a basic conf snippet

Comment: Don't use relative root. Use absolute path starting with `/`

Comment: @TarunLalwani could you provide an example ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154222/discussion-between-tarun-lalwani-and-gianpolo).

Comment: @TarunLlwani ok  thank you